# How do I get data off a hard drive that wont boot up?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, laptop

I have 2 of the same computer laptops. Toshiba Satellite A105-S4384 Computers with windows XP svs pac 3. My original ones hard drive is corrupted. Wont even come up in safe mode. There is lots of data on that drive, not backed up, i need. 
I have put the drive in the other computer and still no go. the good drive works in both.
If I use a SATA to USB cable, Most of the files are not shown because the computer was set up with several user names. Not because there were many users but because if one user account is messed up i would come in through another name.
Is there a way to see all the info on the drive so I can copy it off ? Or, can i use a Windows XP CD (Not the Original) to boot from and be able to see it. Or make a recovery disk from the other similar computer.... not all parts are the same.
In the past I have booted from these CD's and i seem to remember they only want to wipe the drive. 
Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: You have to take ownership of the folders and files in order to see the files assuming the data is even there.

Comment: Try a live Linux CD or this tool ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/287439-emergency-kit-save-your-files-dead-os.html

Comment: Linux is a good solution, as Linux could care less about windows permissions.

Comment: You can use a Live Linux CD to boot and access the data to copy it if this is still possible. If not you can send the HDD to a data recovery specialist.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramhound  notes, you must take ownership of the files and folders on the problem drive.  Once you connect it to a functioning computer with your USB-SATA device, examine the file structure and attempt to open the folders you need (likely Users\User Name) and you will be prompted to take ownership of the files/folders.  This could take a few minutes or more depending on the number of files.

No need to use any boot disks if you have a functional computer and the needed adapter